# Navigate between facebook profiles listener

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, google-chrome

I'm developing a google chrome extension that will insert a button in facebook profile cover, using content script that documented in chrome API i can  insert that button on the refresh the page or open the profile in other window - tab, the problem is open any profile link in the same window - tab will not add that button! I think facebook load the content via AJAX without refresh the page.

I used that code:

```
$("div#contentArea").on("DOMNodeInserted DOMSubtreeModified DOMNodeRemoved",function() { 
// Do somthing
});
```

but it does not fire on navigate between profiles!

How to know if the user is open other profile? I'm thinking to check url for every 1 seconds but is that the final solution?

Comment: try finding the very element contents of which gets changed. in chrome expand the structure and switch btwn profiles - you'll see what's changed.

Comment: @user3455395 I think it will be better to check the url changes.

Comment: I coded simple solution finally it works fine, i used `setTimeout` after two seconds from clicking on profile link, it works perfectly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know it's been long time for this question, but I see it will be better to share the solution, a new one!

It's not good to use any of these `DOMNodeInserted DOMSubtreeModified DOMNodeRemoved`, instead use this API from HTML5 [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver).

There is more than that you can use within `MutationObserver` is this library [mutation-summary](https://code.google.com/p/mutation-summary/).

Thanks for Firefox developers because they share this with me when I submitted this add-on to store.

Best if luck to all.